# How to pad adjacency matrix cells in D3.js style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate the matrix adjacency visualization as demonstrated in [this D3.js example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/). Note that each cell is padded, resulting in a white border around each cell.

This is what I've got so far:

```
img = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(m, interpolation='none')
img.axes.xaxis.tick_top()
img.axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
img.axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
img.axes.spines['top'].set_color('none')
img.axes.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
img.axes.spines['left'].set_color('none')
img.axes.spines['right'].set_color('none')
matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap('gray_r')
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(range(len(m)), G.nodes(), rotation='vertical')
matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(range(len(m)), G.nodes(), rotation='horizontal')
```

I've looked into ways of iterating through each cell, and into other interpolation techniques, but I'd really like to keep no interpolation at all, as I'd like to keep the cells square. Has anyone tried to do this before?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use [`pyplot.pcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) rather than `pyplot.imshow`? With `pcolor` you can get a white border around each cell with the kwarg `edgecolor='w'`.

Comment: Yes! That works. If you add an answer with your comment, I'll select it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the [`pcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) method of `pyplot`, as it accepts a kwarg `edgecolor`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)
y = np.arange(6)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = np.random.rand(5, 5)

ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal') # To make the cells square
ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z,
          edgecolor='white',          # Color of "padding" between cells
          linewidth=2)                # Width of "padding" between cells


plt.show()
```

[image]